# What parameters should I pass to a form's constructor?

Tags: unit-testing, delphi

I am using Delphi XE7 and want to test my program with the unit test provided by DUnit. My code is:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
with Form1 do
Edit3.Text := IntToStr(StrToInt(Edit1.Text) + StrToInt(Edit2.Text));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form1.Edit1.Text := '5';
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Form1.Edit2.Text := '4';
end;

end.
```

So i created a unit test with some test cases for the code:

```
unit TestUnit1;

interface

uses
  TestFramework, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.StdCtrls, Winapi.Windows,
  System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
  Winapi.Messages, Unit1;

type

  TestTForm1 = class(TTestCase)
  strict private
    FForm1: TForm1;
  public
    procedure SetUp; override;
    procedure TearDown; override;
  published
    procedure TestButton1Click;
    procedure TestFormActivate;
    procedure TestFormCreate;
  end;

implementation

procedure TestTForm1.SetUp;
begin
  FForm1 := TForm1.Create;
end;

procedure TestTForm1.TearDown;
begin
  FForm1.Free;
  FForm1 := nil;
end;

procedure TestTForm1.TestButton1Click;
var
  Sender: TObject;
begin
  FForm1.Button1Click(Sender);
  CheckEquals(StrToInt(Form1.Edit1.Text)+StrToInt(Form1.Edit2.Text),StrToInt(Form1.Edit3.Text));
end;

procedure TestTForm1.TestFormActivate;
var
  Sender: TObject;
begin
  FForm1.FormActivate(Sender);
  CheckEquals(5, StrToInt(Form1.Edit1.Text));
end;

procedure TestTForm1.TestFormCreate;
var
  Sender: TObject;
begin
  FForm1.FormCreate(Sender);
  CheckEquals(4, StrToInt(Form1.Edit2.Text));
end;

initialization
  RegisterTest(TestTForm1.Suite);
end.
```

My problem now is that when I want to start the unit test I get an error e2035 Not enough actual parameters at "FForm1 := TForm1.Create;"
What I already know is that the error means that parameters are missing, but I have no idea what parameters i can add so that the code will work. Anyone know any help?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for `TForm.Create` to see what parameters it expects?

Comment: I read the documentation, but since I am mainly programming on Java, I tried to use "null" as a parameter, and that obviously did not work. I just was not aware that for Delphi its not null but nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such errors are readily resolved by reading the documentation. The documentation for this constructor can be found here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Create

> ```
> constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
> ```

So you need to supply the owner. Like this:

```
FForm1 := TForm1.Create(nil);
```

There's no need to supply an owner, I presume, because you are managing the lifetime of the form.